# my homeserver reboots regularly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, reboot

After approx 10 years of having my custom build homeserver/nas I decided to do some maintainance on it. So I carefully cleaned the dust out of it (fully disconnected from power) and did a bios update to the newest bios.
Now my server is rebooting ca 1 time per day and when I try to stream a video (transcoded) via Plex. the reoboot 1 time per day aligns with Plex scheduled tasks timeframe so my guess is that when the system is under load it reboots.

Specs:

- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
- Intel Core i3-4160T, 2C/4T, 3.10GHz
- 2x Kingston ValueRAM DIMM 8GB, DDR3-1600, CL11-11-11 (KVR16N11/8)
- ASRock Z97 Extreme6
- Noctua NH-U12S CPU Fan
- Fractal Design Define R4 Black Pearl
- Fractal Design Newton R3 600W ATX 2.31
- 256GB Samsung SSD as System Disk
- LVM with various disk pairs (Raid 1) as data disks

There are no logs in syslog that would indicate to me why the server reboots.

Since the system is now old and my various disk array is getting full I am considering the following options:

- Fix the server

  - Upgrade Storage and migrate internally to new storage
  - Change to different OS like TrueNas Core (formally FreeNAS) or proxmox
- Buy a separate NAS (synology diskstation ds1821+)

  - migrate data to new NAS
  - try to fix the server or buy a new server
- Build a new server

  - migrate data to new Server

If possible I would of course like to reuse the hardware that I have and not create e-waste. But if it is a hardware and not a software issue, I would probably need to replace everything except case and power supply anyway.
I kinda like the idea of having data and compute separately, because an issue with the server would not impact data availability.

The servers main use case is the plex media server, although I am thinking of adding a GPU and do some stable diffusion workloads on it as well.
Maybe also running [Smarthome Assistent](https://www.home-assistant.io/) to take control of my own smarthome devices.

I like to tinker with IT, but currently I am annoyed that I cannot watch an old movie from my server because it reboots every time I try to watch it. And I already spent hours trying to find the cause.

Comment: When you began to poke inside it, did you take proper esd precautions? And no, momentarily touching metal every so often does not count. If you didn't take precautions, then you could have quite easily zapped any number of components.

Comment: I did not take any particular precautions, other than not touching anything as much as possible.  I used a soft brush and a vacuum, making sure the vacuum does not touch anything. How would I check if any of the hardware got damaged?

Comment: You're on your own, all you can do is gradually replace parts and see what happens and even then, you may not find anything wrong. Just treat it as a lesson learned. Always use esd equipment. A basic wrist strap is cheap compared to having to buy a new cpu/gpu/memory/motherboard/disk/ssd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue!
After the BIOS update I assumed the CMOS got reset, because all my settings and profiles where gone. But I tried to reset the CMOS now before doing the BIOS downgrade and it solved the Issue.
Lesson Learned: ALWAYS clear CMOS after BIOS update!